# Complex number in cosine: $\cos(\log(i^{4i}))$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms

Complex number in cosine: $$\cos(\log(i^{4i}))$$

I put $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$, I get $$\cos(\log(i^{4i}))=\cos(4i\cdot\dfrac{i\pi}{2})=1$$

Is this method correct? I heard someone said that "$\log()$" for complex numbers is multivalues. Does it cause any difference to answer to this question?

Comment: Well, even $i^{4i}$ is multivalued, so you just opened a can of worms

Comment: What exactly is happening? Till now, all the complex numbers had been decent, and their functions also behaved modestly. Suddenly some functions like $\log(z)$ and exponents have started misbehaving. What really happened?

Comment: Well, it's mainly because $e^{2i\pi} = 1$, meaning that $\exp_\Bbb C$ has a period of $2i\pi$, so $\exp$ is no longer injective.

Comment: But the $\cos()$ of that would still be unchanged right? as it is also periodic!?

Comment: The period of $\cos$ is $2\pi$, not $2i\pi$. Moreover, the periods would change if you multiply or divide, or do any arithmetic at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall k \in \Bbb Z: e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)} &=& i \\
\ln i &=& \left\{\dfrac{i\pi}2 + 2ki\pi : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
4i \ln i &=& \left\{-2\pi - 8k\pi : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
\exp(4i \ln i) &=& \left\{\exp(-2\pi - 8k\pi) : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
i^{4i} &=& \left\{\exp(-2\pi - 8k\pi) : k \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
\ln(i^{4i}) &=& \left\{-2\pi - 8k\pi + 2ni\pi : k,n \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
\cos \ln(i^{4i}) &=& \left\{\cos(2ni\pi) : n \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
&=& \left\{\dfrac{\exp(2ni\pi)+\exp(-2ni\pi)}2 : n \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
&=& \left\{\dfrac{1+1}2 : n \in \Bbb Z\right\} \\
&=& 1 \\
\end{array}$$

So fortunately, all branches lead to the same answer.

Comment: I understand it, firstly I missed the other periodic values of $i$. Can you give a hint on how to calculate $\cos(i)$ ?

Comment: Firstly, $\cos z := \dfrac{\exp z + \exp -z}2$

Comment: No what do we do when we don't know this?

Comment: You memorize this or you derive this until you know this.

Comment: Oh I get it thanks!